# Does anyone have an example of a file upload actually working in ASP.NET 4.5 WEBAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Currently I am getting this error: "Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete."

Every example I find on the net and try seems to fail. A few people have said there is a bug in WEB API with file uploads and I need to "\r\n" to the stream, but no one has shown an example of how to do that.